# Media Player Control for .NET Compact Framework

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, media-player

Is there any free media player control library that allows us to play videos in a .NET Compact Framework application?

We tried the one available at http://www.coppercoins.de/post/2008/11/03/WMP-Part-IIIa-Creating-new-Interop-Assembly-for-Mediaplayer.aspx, but having issues with memory problems and  access violation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the [MSDN article on ActiveX Hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx)?  Be aware that [it has a bug](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2008/08/14/BugInMSDNActiveXHostingCode.aspx) in it.

If you need a player for Windows CE (i.e. *not* Windows Mobile) there's an open-source one for DShow [available on Codeplex](https://cemediaplayer.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks a ton. The code provided in the bug + adding a dispose method to the media player control saved me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Windows Media Player Mobile control [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158591.aspx). That allows you to add a Windows Media Player control into your .NET CF application.

Comment: the article points to broken links. the source code and blog referred in the article does not exists any more. Do you know any alternatives?